# Matching key-bindings between modes

Tags: key-bindings, ess, elpy

I'm new to emacs, and I'm trying to set it up as my editor for both python and R. Elpy and Ess are both great, and I'm relying on them a lot. However, I'm used to the Ess key-bindings, and would like the same key-bindings for the similar Elpy commands. For instance, elpy has `elpy-shell-send-statement-and-step` bound to `C-c C-y C-e`, and ess has `ess-eval-region-or-line-and-step` bound to `C-<RET>` (both of these essentially do the same thing).

What is the best way to modify a few of my Elpy key-bindings to match the matching Ess key-bindings in my init.el?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bind the keys you want in the mode map of the given mode. Those keymaps are probably called `ess-mode-map` (for `ess-mode) and `elpy-mode-map` (for `elpy-mode`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `local-set-key` in the major mode's hook. If you do that you don't even need to know the specific keymap for that mode.

You can paste the following lisp code into your init file to have the binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>RET</kbd> for `elpy-shell-send-statement-and-step`.

Disclaimer: I didn't try it. Please test it.

```el
(defun my-elpy-mode-hook-fun ()
 "Function to be installed in `elpy-mode-hook'."
 (local-set-key (kbd "C-<RET>") #'elpy-shell-send-statement-and-step))

(add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook #'my-elpy-mode-hook-fun)
```